# I want to add conditional logic functionality to cforms plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to add conditional logic functionality to cforms plugin. The existing contact form needs the following added feature: User selects a type of product they have from a dropdown on the form. Based on what choice they make, a unique auto-responder email is sent to them. There are going to be 10 different auto-responses depending on which of the 10 drop-down choices they select in the form. All the auto-responses need to be accessible and easily editable within cforms.

Can any one have any clue how to do this. Does cforms provide this ?.
What are the possible ways to do it ?

Is there any alternate plugins which provide this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using Contact Form 7, cForms... for a while, I finally bit the bullet and bought [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/). It's much more polished and is much easier to update than cforms. It will do conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks for help. this will solve the 80 % my need. but only one thing that "There are going to be 10 different auto-responses depending on which of the 10 drop-down choices they select in the form" ? Does this plugins provide this ?